# Finding the symmetries of $f(x)$ given that $f(f(x))=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a function $f$ satisfies the property $f(f(x))=x$, then how would you show that it is an odd function? I tried the following but couldn' t get anywhere. Also, would it have any other symmetries?

$$
f(f(x))=x\\
-f(f(x))=-x\\
f(-f(f(x))=f(-x)
$$
From here I kept trying to get the end result that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ which would show the function is odd.

Comment: Not all such functions are odd, consider $x \mapsto a - x$, $a \neq 0$.

Comment: You're welcome.